# What is this metal bathroom mounting stud called?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

I’m trying to fix up an old bathroom.  The home was built in 1960.  There’s a metal mounting stud coming out of the wall.  In other bathrooms it supports a toothbrush / glass holder.  What is this type of mount called?
[image]

[image]

The reverse of the image seems to read "Reliable".
[image]

Comment: The "where can I find" portion of your question has been removed as off-topic for this site.

Comment: it's kind of hard to see can you make it bigger and increase the illumination?

Comment: It appears that there's an impression of a manufacturer name in the... stuff... around it. What does that actually say, and have you done an internet search on that? Even if the manufacturer is out of business, you may be able to find info on them and their products, browse an old catalogue (remember paper catalogues? People have them, collect them, scan them to PDF & post them online). Once you find that, you'll know what it's called.

Comment: Bertucce? Berludge?

Comment: Maybe jumping ahead, but you may want to contemplate asking "how do I remove this without damaging the tile".   It's easy to find retro accessories to match any period.  They are affordable.  They won't be old and rusty from the get-go, like your authentic replacements will.  And they will be designed for modern bars of soap, tooth brushes, etc that are larger and don't fit in the authentic period accessories.

Comment: You say "in other bathrooms" ... do you mean you have intact fixtures mounted this way in your own or your neighbors' other bathrooms?  Photos of *those*, both mounted and removed from the wall would be of great help.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  There are 5 bathrooms in total.  Only 1 has the missing piece.  I may be able to get to the site later today and take more pics.  I'm looking to find replacement piece(s) to place over the existing stud coming out of the wall.

Comment: It's just a stud, as you said. You won't find a more specific industry term, though there may be a particular name in a diagram by the manufacturer. That won't help you find the product, though, since by then you'll know what it is. What home improvement _problem_ are you trying to solve?

Comment: Finding replacement fixtures, like a soap dish. Where would I begin looking for something like this.  The mirror-image of the print seems to read "Reliable".  I can't seem to find anything about that manufacturer.

Comment: Looks like a standard bracket to me not a stud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call that a type of hanger bolt. Usually there are machine threads where yours shows just a knurled stub, and wood screw threads on the other end so it can be screwed into wood framing in the wall. You don't say how the cup holder is attached to the bolt. Setscrew? Press fit into the back of the holder? It looks like at some point a heaping wad of plumbers putty was jammed in behind the holder, probably to correct looseness.

Comment: Thanks very much for identifying the Hanger Bolt.  I really appreciate it.  I've started searching for accessories for this type of Hanger Bolt but haven't found any thus far.  I'll keep looking.  Again, many thanks.